# Can 'we' be singular?

Tags: grammatical-number, singular-vs-plural

> "No problems, were there?"  "No, sir - house was almost destroyed, but
>   I got him out all right before the Muggles started swarmin' around. He
>   fell asleep as **we was** flyin' over Bristol."  (Harry Potter and the
>   Sorcerer's Stone)

Can we use *was* after *we*, like the example, binding two people as a bunch: as in the case that Chelsea can be both singular and plural?

Comment: _We_ is plural; the question is if _was_ can be used with _we_, and which difference there is between _we were_ and _we was_. The Corpus of Historical American English has 2148 instances of _we was_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In spoken English (british) we often hear *was* after *we*, like in the example. However it is considered uneducated and incorrect.

The author uses it here to demonstrate the characters' social class and/or background, in this case being below the other characters. Note also how other words are changed or dropped, *flying* becoming *flyin'* and no *the* in front of house.

Comment: That also happens in American English.

Answer (score 4):

This is colloquial variation in the vernacular of some parts of British and American English, and is not Standard English. The Standard English equivalent is this:

> He fell asleep as **we were** flying over Bristol.

Generally English learners should avoid "we was" in all cases other than quoted vernacular speech. English learners should avoid its use in English exams, formal writing and non-dialectic speech.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't (or didn't) royalty use 'we' as a singular? Good old Queen Victoria - 'We are not amused'. Or should she have said 'We *is* not amused'...  I jest.